# Two dimensional NIntegration failure - non-numerical values

Tags: numerical-integration, fourier-analysis

I've got this function:

```
E0[x0_, y0_, z_]:= 
    A/w[z]*Exp[-(x0^2 + y0^2)/(w[z]*w[z])]*Exp[(I*2*Pi*(x0^2 + y0^2))/(λ*2*R[z])]*Exp[I*ϕ[z]];
```

Where the `w[z], R[z]` and `Phi[z]` are given as presented [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam).

Second function is as follows:

```
Transmission1[x0_, y0_] := 2*(1 + Cos[((2*Pi)/λ)*x0 - 2*ArcTan[(y0/x0)]]);
```

I want to perform an two dimensional NIntegration:

```
f1[x2_, y2_]:=
    NIntegrate[E0[x0,y0,z]*Transmission1[x0, y0]*Exp[I*(kx1*x0 + ky1*y0)],
        {y0,-0.00001,0.00001},{x0, -0.00001, 0.00001}];
```

where:

```
kx1 = ((2*Pi)/(λ*z))*x2;
ky1 = ((2*Pi)/(λ*z))*y2;
```

For any `{x2,y2}` values I get an error which states:

```
NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand 2\ E^(I\((20000000 π x0 x2)/633+(20000000 π y0 y2)/633))\ (1+Cos[(2000000000\π\x0)/633-2\ ArcTan[Power[<<2>>]\ y0]])
has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-0.00001,0.00001},{-0.00001,0.00001}}"
```

How can I manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in how you define `kx1` and `ky1`. When you call `f1[]`, `x2` and `y2` are substituted in the expression they are immediately visible. And since `kx1` and `ky1` don't explicitly depend on `z` and `x2` and `y2`, these values aren't substituted.

To fix this, you should define `kx1` and `ky1` as functions:

```
kx1[z_,x2_] = ((2*Pi)/(λ*z))*x2;
ky1[z_,y2_] = ((2*Pi)/(λ*z))*y2;
```

and use as functions in `f1[]`.

Also, definition of your `f1` lacks additional argument of `z`, so you should add it too (if you don't set its value somewhere, of course - but I couldn't deduce it from your question):

```
f1[x2_,y2_,z_]:=...
```

and supply it too for numerical integration to be possible.